# Language Scheme, leaf-labelled trees

Tags: scheme, racket

;; A leaf-labelled tree (Llt) is one of the following:

;; * empty

;; * (cons l1 l2), where l1 is a non-empty Llt and l2 is an Llt

;; * (cons v l), where v is an Int and l is an Llt

How to locate a specific list in a leaf-labelled tree?
For example, if I have a parameter n, and I want to find which list contains n. What should I do?

Comment: What is a list?  You've only defined a `leaf-labelled-tree`, mentioned `empty` and `Int`.  Based on your description, lists fit nowhere (only `Int` and `Llt`).

Comment: So your problem is to find the subtree that contains `n`.

Comment: This looks like a HtDP-style question, in which case the original questioner should use a Design Recipe approach to attack this problem. i.e. http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_two.html#%28part._ch~3adesign-lists%29  Specifically, where are the examples of data, the test cases, the function template for developing functions that work on that data structure?  By trying to skip the steps and leaping to coding, the original questioner risks getting stuck very easily.

Answer (score 1):

So you have the empty tree, which is `'()` or `(cons x y)` where x and y can be either  integer value or a subtree. Basically it's just plain list structure with numbers?

Since this might be homework I'm just giving you some hints on the way:

```
(define (locate tree x)
  (cond ;; if it's not a pair we didn't find it
        ((not (pair? <??>)) #f)
        ;; if the car or the cdr of tree is x, return tree
        ((or (eqv? <??> <??>) (eqv? <??> <??>)) <??>)
        ;; answer must be in either the car OR the cdr
        (else (or (locate <??> x) (locate <??> x)))))
```

`eqv?` will be #t if the two are `eq?` to so you can actually search a part of a tree too. Eg.

```
(define tree '(1 (2 (3 (4) 5 6 7 8)))) 
(locate tree 4)  ; ==> (4)
(locate tree (locate tree 4)) ; ==> ((4) 5 6 7 8)
```

But it only works for structure that are `eq?`. Eg this won't work unless you use `equal?` instead:

```
(locate tree '(4)) ; ==> #f
```